# What format do Microsoft Lists require date/time column values to be in when adding them from Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-lists

I want to add the current date/time to a date/time column.

What format do Microsoft Lists require date/time column values to be in when adding them from Power Automate?

I am using the `Convert time zone` action to convert `utcNow()` to AEST (UTC +10 hours).

This format string works fine if the column is date only (no time):

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

However, I don't know what format string to use when the column is date AND time.

[image]

I can see that the `For a selected file` action in a flow returns values like these for date/time columns:

```
2022-09-29T06:30:00Z
```

In this example, the time is displayed in the SharePoint list as:

```
29/09/2022 16:30  [ representing the date/time in AEST (UTC +10 hours) ]
```

I've tried to find the answer reading articles like these but had no luck:

[Datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/datetime)

[Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

[How to customize or format Date and Time values in a flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/how-to-customize-or-format-date-and-time-values-in-flow)

Comment: You can pass values in `2022-09-29T06:30:00Z` format as well as you can direct pass `utcNow()`. Displayed date and time in SharePoint can be different based on regional settings. Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Date-Times-in-Sharepoint-List-converting/td-p/969700) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Incorrect-time-showing-in-Sharepoint-List-send-by-Flow/td-p/405449) for more information.

Comment: I think I had an incorrect understanding, I thought if I wanted to add a timestamp representing 'right now', I needed to convert UTC to my timezone first.  however, it seems I need to populate the list with values that are *in UTC timezone* because the locale settings of SharePoint will update them to display the values that are correct in the local timezone.  I just tested `update item` with the following values and they both added the correct value:  `formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')` or just `utcNow()`.  You can add this as an answer if you like and I can accept it.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! I have added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint always stores the date & time values in UTC format and displays the date & time values in lists based on regional settings of site.

You can pass values to date & time column in `2022-09-29T06:30:00Z` (`formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')`) format as well as you can direct pass `utcNow()` as value from Power automate flow.

For more information, check this: [Incorrect time showing in SharePoint List send by Flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Incorrect-time-showing-in-Sharepoint-List-send-by-Flow/td-p/405449)